# Setting Variable In One Class And Returning Value To Another

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, boolean

I am learning C# and am attempting to create a `public bool` class variable that's value will be set in one class, and passed back to the calling class.  I have attempted the code below, but the bool value is **ALWAYS** false when it returns back to `VerifyForm` even though stepping through my code, I see that in my class `IntelOrNo` the value is properly being set.

For a more experienced C# winforms programmer, how should I code this so that the value of my variable `rttam` is properly set and passed from class to class?

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CTX
{
    public partial class VerifyForm : Form
    {
        public static IntelOrNo ai = new IntelOrNo();

        public VerifyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ai.rttam = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ai.rttam = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public partial class IntelOrNo : Form
    {
        public bool rttam = false;

        public IntelOrNo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDoThisWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerifyForm EH = new VerifyForm();
            EH.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            EH.ShowDialog();

            if (rttam)
            {

            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you might want to spend a few letters to make better names (*rttam*).  Then, your bool never "returns" anywhere,. it is always part of the `ai` object.  Where you check anything is not clear since VerifyForm closes right after you change `rttam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly i would just remove the static variable. and give the `VerifyForm` class a constructor that expects the `IntelOrNo` Form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CTX
{
    public partial class VerifyForm : Form
    {
        public IntelOrNo _parent;

        public VerifyForm(IntelOrNo parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _parent.rttam = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _parent.rttam = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public partial class IntelOrNo : Form
    {
        public bool rttam = false;

        public IntelOrNo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDoThisWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerifyForm EH = new VerifyForm(this);
            EH.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            EH.ShowDialog();

            if (rttam)
            {

            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you really just want to open a yes no dialogue box i would recommend using `MessageBox` in your `btnDoThisWork_Click` event like this.

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
     //do something
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
     //do something else
}
```

Comment: Ups forgot to remove the static from parent^^.

Comment: This works - thank you so much!  I am confused as to how calling the second form like this `VerifyForm EH = new VerifyForm(this);` and having a variable in the second form `public static IntelOrNo _parent;` allows the value to be passed from form to form/class to class?

Comment: Well your start up Form seems to be IntelOrNo. By creating the other form on the button press "btnDoThisWork_Click", you can give the Form you are opening a reference to IntelOrNo. Because of this your VerifyForm can change the Variables in this reference.

Comment: Ah - that makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the valuable insight and explenation!!!

Comment: No problem glad i could help ^^. Even though if you just want to achieve a yes no Dialogue and want the result i really recommend the MessageBox :).

Comment: I am using a winform and removing the minimize, close buttons and adding a button for yes and a button for no to confirm that the user actually wants to perform an action before it executes.  Creating a custom winform, with an image, and custom header, and labels explaining ramifications was the best solution I was able to come up with.

Comment: Seems like a good solution then,(since it's probably not possible to insert images in a MessageBox).^^

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the class reference into the partial class through the constructor and return the variable that way, though I'm not sure from that code snippet where you are trying to access rttam in the VerifyForm class.

The reason it may not be working at the moment is because you are creating multiple instances of the classes. In the IntelOrNo class you declare a *new* VerifyForm class, this creates an entirely new instance of that class and *does not* reference the class you originally had.

Currently your code is doing this:

1. Create new instance of VerifyForm
2. Create new instance of IntelOrNo
3. Create new instance of VerifyForm

You will not be able to pass variables into the first VerifyForm through the second VerifyForm, they are different classes.

Back to the potential fix, using the **this** keyword, you can pass the first VerifyForm into IntelOrNo and access it from there.

```
  using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CTX
{
    public partial class VerifyForm : Form
    {
        public static IntelOrNo ai = new IntelOrNo(this);//Pass this class as a parameter

        public VerifyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ai.rttam = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ai.rttam = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    public partial class IntelOrNo : Form
    {
        public bool rttam = false;
        private VerifyForm parent

        public IntelOrNo(VerifyForm _parent)
        {
            parent = _parent; //Sets the private parent variable to the initial VerifyForm class, from here you can access the initial VerifyForm class through parent.whatever
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDoThisWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerifyForm EH = new VerifyForm(); //This creates a NEW instance of the class, not what you want (I think)

            parent.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            parent.ShowDialog();

            if (rttam)
            {

            }           
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, if I've misunderstood the question feel free to clarify and I will attempt to answer again. :)

Comment: In my verifyform class I am only setting the value of rttam - I want to access the value that is set to verifyform.rttam in the IntelOrNo class.  Does that make sense?  I'll test your solution :)

Comment: You could access it using parent.rttam from the IntelOrNo class, but the variable rttam is actually declared from inside IntelOrNo, so that would have to be changed first. Let me know if you need further help and I will amend my answer then.

Comment: I get a compile error of 'Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer' on the line public static IntelOrNo ai = new IntelOrNo(this)

Comment: Is there a specific reason IntelOrNo ai is static?

Comment: Nope - that is just how VS set it when it was created.

Comment: It then presents compile error of 'Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context'

Comment: Maybe try moving initialisation to the constructor of VerifyForm? So it would declare it as IntelOrNo ai; and then in the VerifyForm constructor put ai = new IntelOrNo(this)